# Matrix Transpose

Tags: matrices

I have a vector that I sliced into k vectors to create a matrix that is kxn. Let's call this matrix A (kxn) when I multiply the transpose of A (nxk) with A(kxn) I get a square matrix B(nxn) what does B signify?

Comment: Please try to be more clear. Are you *slicing* into $k$ vectors all with the same size? And what is $k$? Any divisor of $n$? Finally, the question itself might be seen as going against this part of the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq): What kind of questions should I not ask here?

Comment: I am slicing into k vectors all the same size (n). All I'm simply asking is: if I have a matrix A(kxn) and I multiply it as follows A^T*A, what do I get? Is it an autocorrelation? A covariance variance matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a matrix made of column vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$, then $A^TA$ is the [Gramian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) (but it has size $k\times k$, not $n\times n$).

> If the vectors are centered random variables, the Gramian is proportional to the covariance matrix

The $n\times n$ matrix would be $AA^T$. This is the sum of [outer products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $v_i\times v_j$ over all $i$ and $j$; but it's probably better understood as the Gramian matrix of the rows of $A$.